# Conditional filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have a **tel** filter which I will like to be applied only if a condition is meet. How can I do it?

This is my current code:

```
<span class="display-block" ng-show="event.category == 'Entry' && v" ng-repeat="(k, v) in properties">
  <strong>{{k | sentenceCase}}:</strong> {{v | tel}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to use ternary operator just like you would do in JS:

```
{{ condition ? (v | tel) : v }}
```

Comment: I understand now, another quick question: what if I want to add more filters later? Should be something like this: {{ condition ? (v | tel) : v; condition ? (v | address) : v }}

Correct?

Comment: @user1262904 The same condition for all filters?

Comment: Here is an example of one more unconditional filter: `{{ ( condition ? (v | tel) : v ) | linky }}`. With multiple conditions it's not worth using this approach since expression becomes hard to read. In this case it's better to create custom filtering function in controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
<strong>{{k | condition?filterByThisIfTrue |orFilterByThis}}:</strong>
```